# iOS Audio: What's the difference between preferredPolarPattern and selectedPolarPattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

What's the difference between preferredPolarPattern and selectedPolarPattern?
I've read through the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription/1616450-supportedpolarpatterns?language=objc) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription/1616446-preferredpolarpattern?language=objc). Maybe I'm being dense, but I can't see a difference between the two. Any ideas?

From the docs:

```
/// Describes the currently selected polar pattern.  Will be nil for data sources that have no
/// selectable patterns.
@property (readonly, nullable) AVAudioSessionPolarPattern selectedPolarPattern API_AVAILABLE(ios(7.0), tvos(9.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos, macos);

/// Describes the preferred polar pattern.  Will be nil for data sources that have no selectable
/// patterns or if no preference has been set.
@property (readonly, nullable) AVAudioSessionPolarPattern preferredPolarPattern API_AVAILABLE(ios(7.0), tvos(9.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos, macos);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about the process of reading Apple's documentation than a pure programming question.

To start, we should be considering the [`AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription?language=objc) object, in particular honing in on the *Configuring Microphone Directivity* subsection.

It is important to read around properties and methods as sometimes important information is not replicate in all relevant articles. If the function of an object, property, or method is not clear, then remember to also look at the *See Also* section.

In this instance we have two properties that at first glance seems to mirror the same information.

- [`selectedPolarPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription/1616619-selectedpolarpattern?language=objc): *The data source’s active polar pattern.*
- [`preferredPolarPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription/1616446-preferredpolarpattern?language=objc): *The preferred directivity configuration for the data source.*

Both properties deal with the polar pattern of the microphone. The keywords that differentiate them here are *active* and *preferred*. Even then, that does not fill in all the blanks, specifically when these two properties hold different values.

This is when we should read around the documentation to get more clues. Are there any other properties or methods that relate to these? There is `supportedPolarPatterns`, but that  is just an array of polar patterns supported by the device. There *is* a setter method, for `preferredPolarPattern`, [`setPreferredPolarPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription/1616516-setpreferredpolarpattern?language=objc). There isn't a `setSelectedPolarPattern` or `setPolarPattern` method. Weird!. This should be a flag about the behaviour of the method.

Remember, with Apple's APIs you do not necessarily have control of when certain actions will take place.

This is confirmed in the *Discussion* of `setPreferredPolarPattern`, where we read:

> Calling this method requests a change to the selected polar pattern. To determine whether the change has taken effect, inspect the selectedPolarPattern property.

This confirms when `preferredPolarPattern` will differ from `selectedPolarPattern`

Also take note:

> If the data source and its owning port are in use, using this method to change the directivity configuration is likely to result in a route reconfiguration.
>
> **Set a preferred polar pattern only after setting the audio session’s category and mode, and activating the session.**

Comment: Alright, fair enough. So, is there a way to determine _when_ the change has taken effect? I'm not seeing a notification or delegate for this anywhere.

Comment: You would likely check this somewhere else in your AVAudioSession hierarchy. It is sort of moot to an extent, as either a request will fail and you can check the returned `BOOL` and the populated `NSError`, or the request was successful and the polar pattern is going to change when it’s going to change. Without an understanding of use case and a working example it is a little tricky. I would argue that is a different question than the one presented though.

Comment: That said, given changing the polar may result in re routing, you likely want to look here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes